# Which phonetic symbol for "consonne occlusive dentale voisée"?

Tags: phonétique

On https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aide:Alphabet_phon%C3%A9tique_fran%C3%A7ais, the sound *consonne occlusive dentale voisée* uses *d* while on the page the *d* links to https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_occlusive_dentale_vois%C3%A9e the symbol used is *d̪*.

Which is right? And does anyone have a sound sample? Wikipedia is missing it for this sound (and a couple of others, is there a complete collection somewhere?).

Edit: same question for https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_occlusive_dentale_sourde

Edit 2: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_ouverte_centrale_non_arrondie

Edit 3: hmm, *ɛ* and *ɛ:* point to the same side/sound sample?

Edit 4: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_ouverte_post%C3%A9rieure_non_arrondie (different symbols)

Edit 5: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_mi-ouverte_ant%C3%A9rieure_non_arrondie

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_mi-ouverte_ant%C3%A9rieure_arrondie

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_mi-ouverte_post%C3%A9rieure_arrondie

Comment: French only has one /d/, so there is no point in specifying [d], [d̪], or [d̠] when transcribing French in IPA, and it's generally transcribed as /d/. [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_dental_and_alveolar_stops#Dental_or_denti-alveolar) gives both sounds, although, confusingly, they change the vowel as well: [dɑ] and [d̪a]. (This might explained if the first is from an English speaker and the second from a French speaker.)

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the [d̪](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_occlusive_dentale_vois%C3%A9e) et [t̪](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consonne_occlusive_dentale_sourde) pages completely? They explain you how to make the sounds. However, if you still want to listen to them, you can go on [this page](https://www.podcastfrancaisfacile.com/phonetique-2/tableau-des-sons-du-francais.html).

For your second edit, you must know that in France, we pronounce it the same way as a normal (french) "a". Only some rare regions still make the difference, so don't learn this sound, you won't need it.

In phonetic, the two triangles ː after a vowell mean that it must be longer, as in english ship /i/ or sheep /iː/.

The sound ɑ is the same as the sound ä described above, but we don't make the difference and always say it a, except in some regions.

The sound ɔ is the same as in the word spa in english. You can listen to it [here again](https://www.podcastfrancaisfacile.com/phonetique-2/tableau-des-sons-du-francais.html)

Finally, I know that the sound œ can be really difficult to pronounce for some foreigners. Again, listen to it on this [website](https://www.podcastfrancaisfacile.com/phonetique-2/tableau-des-sons-du-francais.html), and if you still don't succeed, you can go on this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=66g1aLYrZmI).

Good luck!

Comment: First, the sound ɔ is ***not*** the sound of *spa* in English (except maybe for a few people from Boston and the Western U.S.); the sound of *spa* is the same as the sound of *pâte* in French, assuming you don't pronounce *pâte* the same as *patte*). The sound ɔ is the sound of *caught* or *fort*.

Comment: Second, the IPA symbols [ɑ] and [ä] aren't officially the same sound (although they represent same phoneme when talking about french, so don't worry about the difference).

Comment: Actually, listening to the website you linked to, I suspect that the vowel in *proche* may have changed since they assigned the IPA symbols, and it now may be closer to the vowel of *cot*, [ɒ], in British English (this move was probably possible because the vowel of *pâte* has disappeared from many dialects of French). This vowel doesn't exist in American English, but I would still say the closest American vowel is in *caught* and not *spa*.